# Is there a Unix-type command to kill all processes with a certain name?

Tags: command, command-line-interface

I run a script called "delayed_job" for a Ruby on Rails application. One of the options is to run this proc with a separate monitor proc. When the main proc dies, the monitor will spawn a new one. I can also run multiple processes. Each will have its own associated monitor process.

The script gives a way to kill the main processes, but not the monitor processes. I want to kill all of them.

A command of:

```
ps -ef|grep delayed
```

yields:

```
42011    29423     1  0 Sep25 ?        00:00:02 delayed_job.0_monitor                
42011    29428     1  0 Sep25 ?        00:00:02 delayed_job.1_monitor                
42011    29434     1  0 Sep25 ?        00:00:02 delayed_job.2_monitor                
42011    29437     1  0 Sep25 ?        00:00:01 delayed_job.3_monitor                
42011    23359     1 10 Oct19 ?        03:12:49 delayed_job.0                        
42011     8607     1  5 Oct19 ?        00:58:42 delayed_job.3                        
42011    21442     1 44 12:31 ?        01:02:03 delayed_job.2                        
42011    23092     1  4 14:18 ?        00:01:22 delayed_job.1                        
42011    23861 23763  0 14:51 pts/5    00:00:00 grep delayed
```

I want to kill all of them, or at least the monitors. How can I kill these (with the exception of the grep command itself)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/742/kill-the-undesired-unix-processes-in-one-go/ has a nice write up of the usual answer for generic unix: pipe ps to grep, then to awk, then to xargs.

As another poster mentioned, beware any glib answer that throws around "killall", since it has a radically different purpose on AIX and Solaris (at least) than it does on Linux.  Running killall as root on Solaris is a "resume generating event".

Answer (score 3):

Outside of the above pkill and killall answers, you can do the following, assuming you want to kill process "foo"

```
ps -ef | grep [f]oo | awk {'print $1'} | xargs kill
```

The `grep [f]oo` means that grep will not match the grep command itself, so it will just kill processes named "foo".

Comment: I needed to use $2 on my Windows 10 bash

Answer (score 2):

If you are running a linux machine, the killall command seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

`pkill` and `killall` are variants of this.

```
# pkill vim

# killall vim
```

Both has extended documentation in their respective man-pages.